# Imprimir un árbol binario por niveles de forma horizontal en C++

Tags: c++, dev-c++, árboles-binarios

estoy realizando una evaluación de árboles binarios, y entre las preguntas me piden que imprima el árbol de forma horizontal por niveles, he leído las respuestas pero ninguna se parece a la sintaxis de mi código.

 También me pidieron imprimir el código de forma vertical, hice una segunda sintaxis usando la función gotoxy para eso.
 

 Agradecería mucho si me pueden ayudar.

Dejo el código acá, es el mismo de Martín Cruz, solo hice algunas modificaciones ya que su código presentaba errores y realmente no compilaba, al menos en mi desarrollador:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<windows.h>
using namespace std;
struct nodo{
    int nro;
    struct nodo *izq, *der;
};

typedef struct nodo *ABB;
ABB crearNodo(int x){
    ABB nuevoNodo = new(struct nodo);
    nuevoNodo->nro = x;
    nuevoNodo->izq = NULL;
    nuevoNodo->der = NULL;
    
    return nuevoNodo;
}

void insertar(ABB &arbol, int x){ // comandos de qué hará y cómo se hará el árbol
    if(arbol == NULL){
        arbol = crearNodo(x);
    }
    else if(x < arbol->nro){
        insertar(arbol->izq, x);
    }
    else if(x > arbol->nro){
        insertar(arbol->der, x);
    }
}

void preOrden(ABB arbol){
    if(arbol!=NULL){
        cout<<arbol->nro<<" ";
        preOrden(arbol->izq);
        preOrden(arbol->der);
    }
}

void enOrden(ABB arbol){
    if(arbol!=NULL){
        enOrden(arbol->izq);
        cout<<arbol->nro<<" ";
        enOrden(arbol->der);
    }
}

void postOrden(ABB arbol){
    if(arbol!=NULL){
        postOrden(arbol->izq);
        postOrden(arbol->der);
        cout<<arbol->nro<<" ";
    }
}

void verArbol(ABB arbol, int n){
    if(arbol!=NULL){
        return;
        verArbol(arbol->der, n+1);
        for (int i=0; i<n; i++){
        cout<<" ";
        cout<<arbol->nro<<endl;
        }
        verArbol(arbol->izq, n+1);
    }
}

int main(){
    ABB arbol = NULL;
    int n;
    int x;
    
    cout<<"\t\nARBOL BINARIO DE BUSQUEDA\t\n"<<endl;
    cout<<"Numero de arboles del nodo"<<endl;
    cin>>n;
    cout<<endl;
    
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
        cout<<"Numero de nodos "<<i+1<<": "<<endl;
        cin>>x;
        insertar(arbol, x);
    }
    cout<<"Mostrando ABB"<<endl;
    verArbol(arbol, 0);
    cout<<endl;
    cout<<"Recorridos del ABB"<<endl;
    cout<<"En orden"<<endl; enOrden(arbol);
    cout<<endl;
    cout<<"Pre orden"<<endl; preOrden(arbol);
    cout<<endl;
    cout<<"Post orden"<<endl; postOrden(arbol);
    cout<<endl;
    cout<<endl;
    
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

La idea de dejar el código completo acá es porque quizás a alguien más lo esté necesitando y lo pueda utilizar.

Actualmente, el código imprime el árbol de forma lineal, me gustaría que me lo imprimiera de la siguiente forma: 

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Seria bueno que en una imagen mostraras que es "forma horizontal"

Comment: Listo, ya hice la corrección en la publicación para que se aprecie bien lo que quiero que haga el código.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Principalmente veo que te faltan los espacios necesarios por cada nodo, puedes realizar ciclos *for* e interar entre cada nodo poniendo n cantidad de espacios enmedio.

Cuando yo estuve viendo los árboles, un yutuber me ayudó mucho, porque muestra la teoria y el codigo de como implementar cada aspecto que un arbol binario requiere... Te lo dejo y espero te funcione.
Sugerencia, no te atengas a que si ya tienes tu código funcional no lo vas a cambiar, en la vida de desarrollador te vas a topar con varios que, pueda que, no les guste tu código.
[Programación en C++ || Árboles || Mostrar el árbol completo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eZfXKHrMyo8)

Comment: La verdad no había intentado realizar grandes modificaciones en el código ya que este fue el que nos dio el profesor, y no sé si le satisfaga que realice modificaciones o eso vaya a afectar mi nota, por eso quería conocer la posibilidad de hacer que se imprimiera sin modificar el código; a mi también me gusta mucho como programa el dueño de ese canal de YouTube, gracias por tu aporte. :)

Comment: @LauraaMorales Sii entiendo tu miedo, un buen profesor se sentiria orgulloso que hayas modificado y realizado con exito la tarea, pero si el no es de ese tipo, de igual manera puedes ver el video, enseña la logica , solo adaptalo a tu codigo

Comment: Te lo agradezco muchísimo. :)